# How do I sync Smart Mailboxes / Smart Albums across my devices?

Tags: mail.app, photos, ios, macos

I'm on macOS Monterey 12.0.1 & iOS / iPad OS 15, and I have created some Smart Mailboxes in Mail.app and Smart Albums in Photos.app on my Mac, but they don't seem to sync across my devices.

If syncing of Smart Mailboxes / Smart Albums isn't supported by Apple (yet), what can I do to achieve the same things the easy way?

Comment: You have two different topics merged into one question.  The solution for mail will not be the same as the solution for photos.  You should split this into two different questions and include the results of trying the solutions already provided in other questions (on each topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fsb. Isn't the answer that ios apps don't have smart folders.   So the answer is no you cant

Comment: Any idea why Apple still hasn't add iOS support for Smart Mailboxes / Smart Albums in 2021?